# python,if,что-то вроде обучения нейронных сетей

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть такой код:

```
import numpy as np
inp = input().lower()
def hard():
    global hello
    hello = 0



    if "а" in inp:
        pass
    if "б" in inp:
        pass
    if "в" in inp:
        hello = hello + 1
    if "г" in inp:
        pass
    if "д" in inp:
       pass
    if "е" in inp:
        pass
    if "ё" in inp:
        pass
    if "ж" in inp:
        pass
    if "з" in inp:
        pass
    if "и" in inp:
        hello = hello + 1
    if "й" in inp:
        pass
    if "к" in inp:
       pass

    if "л" in inp:
        pass
    if "м" in inp:
        pass
    if "н" in inp:
        pass
    if "о" in inp:
        pass
    if "п" in inp:
        hello = hello + 1
    if "р" in inp:
        hello = hello + 1
    if "с" in inp:
        pass
    if "т" in inp:
        hello = hello + 1
    if "у" in inp:
        pass
    if "ф" in inp:
        pass
    if "х" in inp:
        pass
    if "ц" in inp:
        pass
    if "ч" in inp:
        pass
    if "ш" in inp:
        pass
    if "щ" in inp:
        pass
    if "ы" in inp:
        pass
    if "ь" in inp:
        pass
    if "э" in inp:
        pass
    if "ю" in inp:
        pass
    if "я" in inp:
        pass
    return hello
    return hay
    return name
hard()
if hello >= 3:
    print("вы имели в виду : привет ")

else:
    print("ну я не знаю")
```

в нем для примера есть слово привет . Добавлять каждое слово в ручную лень,
как сделать что бы программа сама разбивала слово на буквы и добавляла его в свой if причем добавлять будет определенно то есть когда она не поняла слово
она спросила хочу ли я его добавить в ее знания если да то я введу например
красивый(само слово которое надо добавить) nice(значение которое она будет отдавать при распозновании красивый. Не знаю возможно ли такое, если кто-то знает отпишитесь пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Короче Склифосовский!

Comment: А зачем? . . . .

Comment: Надо...........

Comment: Скорее всего не надо, а вы просто пытаетесь решить свою задачу неправильным способом

Comment: Ну если "надо", так и "меняйте". Как вопрос поставлен - такой ответ и получите)

Comment: Задача всё равно не конца понятна, каков должен быть конечный результат такого "обучения" и что должен делать каждый if?

Comment: После обучения слово должно разложиться на буквы и добавить свою букву в свой IF например слово «красивый» к должна добавиться в if который отслеживает наличее на входе буквы К .я просто сам задолбаюсь раскладывать слова на буквы и добавлять в ручную (заранее спасибо за терпение я просто не идеально разбираюсь в python•е да и мне только 12

Comment: По вашему описанию вообще не понятна суть задачи. Но, кажется, if вам тут не нужны. Возможно вам нужно хранить буквы в какой-то структуре типа множества или словаря, чтобы программа на основе их присутствия там принимала решение. Но опять-таки - без внятной формулировки задачи ничего конкретного тут сказать нельзя.

Comment: "писал на скорую руку" а вот не надо так писать. Посидите, подумайте, сформулируйте нормально вопрос, приложите ваш код. Тогда и помогать вам будет проще. А то вы значит не хотите время на оформление вопроса потратить, а кто-то должен будет за вас потратить время, чтобы этот вопрос понять и добиться от вас нормального оформления. Это неуважение к сообществу вообще-то.

Comment: Хорошо, буду дома, приведу КОД и остальное

Comment: Слова можно без проблем добавлять в словарь наподобие `знания = {"красивый": {"порог": 5, "значение": "nice"}}` и потом проверять ввод на соответствие знакомым словам чем-то вроде `for знакомое_слово in знания.keys(): for буква in inp: if буква in знакомое_слово:` и так далее. Дополнение такого словаря нужными знаниями не должно быть проблемой, и никакие if'ы редактировать не надо

Comment: спасибо!Постораюсь понять и сделаю. Еще раз спасибо

Comment: я не могу понять как оно будет работать.  
hello = ("привет",1,"hello")
(a1,b1,c1) = hello
inp = input()
global lol
lol = 0
for a1 in inp:
    lol = lol + 1
print(lol)
сделал так но тогда оно будет подсчитывать по кол-ву букв .А как сделать правильно подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

Это возможно, если вы будете редактировать файл стандартными инструментами python. Об этом можно прочитать [тут](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/fajly-rabota-s-fajlami.html). Однако, надо понимать, что вовремя выполнения программа выгружается в оперативную память и по факту, ваши изменения можно будет заметить только при повторном запуске (что в принципе, можно сделать в коде) Но опять же, как сказали коллеги выше "зачем"? Использование таких инструментов является грубым тоном в программировании. Также он может привести к непредвиденным ошибкам. Расскажите подробнее о вашей задаче и я думаю сообщество StackOverflow поможет найти вам наиболее оптимальное решение.